# Determine responding application to Keyboard in c#

Tags: c#, keyboard

we suppose a user is writing something let say he wrote "test". Here we can use system Hook or something like this to determine what was written.but if I want to determine what was written and what application the word was written on.

> Example:
>
> I wrote hello world in notepad  the application must response that
>   hello world was written on notepad.

can be done in c# ?!

Comment: Bing "Writing keylogger in C#", first result gives you a tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you capture a key event you can use `GetForegroundWindow()` to get a handle to the active window (the window which the user is currently working on) then call `GetWindowText()` to get the title of that window.

You can download [this project file from codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C). In HookManager.Windows.cs file add the following:

```cs
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
[DllImport("user32.dll")] 
public static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);
```

Then in the key capture events you can retrieve the window where the user was typing in:

```cs
var sb = new StringBuilder(100);
var hCurrentWindow = HookManager.GetForegroundWindow();
HookManager.GetWindowText(hCurrentWindow, sb, 100);
```

`sb` will hold the caption of that window.